# Alocação Dinâmica de Ponteiros em C++

Tags: c++, ponteiro, struct, alocação

Estou precisando criar uma rotina de proteção na função de remoção. Porquê dá erro ao remover o último item?

*A função:*

```
// Remover o primeiro cliente
void cadRemover(){
  lista=ini; // Volta ao início
  aux = lista; // Copia o 1º para aux
  lista = lista->prox; // Move a lista para o próximo
  delete aux; // Deleta aux
}
```

O source [completo](http://pastebin.com/3iu8h9Qw).

Comment: Arranjei um jeitinho, mas acredito que ainda não seja a melhor opção... (Estou comentando pq ainda não possuo pontuação suficiente - 10 - para postar resposta)

Comment: Pode ser uma restrição de *timing*, mas não de reputação: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges . . . . Editei sua pergunta para deixar o texto mais fluido, mas fiquei na dúvida quanto ao título, por favor, confira se corresponde ao seu problema.

Comment: Qual o erro? Seja mais específico.

Comment: Achei que ficou mais inteligível sim @brasofilo, obrigado !!

Comment: @dxhj, a função como está na pergunta gera o seguinte erro ao remover-se o último item: `double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x00000000010cf050 ***
Aborted (core dumped)`. Consegui resolver com um if else, mas ainda não é o ideal porquê não utiliza aritmética de ponteiros...

Comment: Isso ocorre porque você está tentando liberar algo que já está liberado.

Comment: Imagino que o motivo seja que o último receba um índice 0. E, uma vez que o array não pode conter índices negativos, dá-se o erro. Como não encontrei outra maneira, fiz o controle pelo if...

Answer (score 3):

A resposta direta a sua pergunta é que você esta utilizando `ini` como início da lista mas ao remover um elemento não atualiza o seu valor. Como não faz isso você deleta o mesmo elementos várias vezes causando o erro visto no Windows.
Sem modificar mais nada, o código da sua função teria que mudar para:

```
// Remover o primeiro cliente
void cadRemover(){
  lista=ini; // Volta ao início
  aux = lista; // Copia o 1º para aux
  lista = lista->prox; // Move a lista para o próximo
  ini = lista; // Atualiza o novo início da lista
  delete aux; // Deleta aux
}
```

Porém, vale notar que este código pode ser simplificado se levarmos em conta que o campo `prox` do último elemento da lista é igual a `NULL` e removermos variáveis desnecessárias. Ficamos assim com:

```
// Remover o primeiro cliente
void cadRemover(){
  if (ini == NULL)
  {
    return; // Lista vazia.
  }
  cadastro *aux = ini; // Copia o 1º para aux
  ini = ini->prox; // Move a lista para o próximo
  delete aux; // Deleta aux
}
```

Agora que o problema foi resolvido acho importante comentar algumas coisas sobre o seu código já que apresenta diversas escolhas não recomendáveis.

- Utilização de variáveis globais desnecessárias

Um exemplo claro deste problema é a variável `aux` que é declarada como global mas só é utilizada na função `cadRemover`. O mesmo pode ser dito sobre a variável `lista` que só é utilizada em `cadExibir`. Você deve sempre tentar declarar suas variáveis no escopo mais próximo possível da sua utilização, nesses casos dentro das funções.

- Múltiplas expressões na mesma linha.

Em diversos trechos você coloca mais de uma expressão na mesma linha. Esta prática apenas dificulta a leitura do código e torna certos pedaços mais confusos.

Exemplo:

```
cout<<"\nEntre com a quantidade de clientes para cadastrar: ";cin>>n;cin.get();

float *alunos, soma=0, media;
```

Poderiam ser:

```
cout<<"\nEntre com a quantidade de clientes para cadastrar: ";
cin>>n;
cin.get();

float *alunos;
float soma = 0.0f;
float media;
```

- Usar `using namespace std` no início do programa

Essa é uma prática muito comum entre pessoas que estão começando a usar C++ mas que não é aconselhável. Um dos grandes problemas ao fazer isto é *colisão de nomes* (quando duas estruturas/funções/etc são declaradas com o mesmo nome). `namespace`s foram introduzidos na linguagem para ajudar na organização dos programas e evitar essas *colisões* principalmente quando se utiliza bibliotecas produzidas por terceiros. Sendo assim, é recomendado que se utilize o nome totalmente qualificado das estruturas/funções/etc, como `std::cout`, `std::cin` e não utilizar `using namespace std`.

- Utilização de `int` como `bool`

Você cria as variáveis `f1`, `f2` e `f3` para determinar se uma determinada etapa foi ou não realizada. Para isto seria mais interessante utilizar variáveis do tipo `bool` que foi criado justamente para representar verdadeiro/falso.